# How can I prevent DC Legends from constantly restarting?

Tags: android, dc-legends

Just about every time my phone's screen turns off for more than a few seconds, DC Legends restarts to the title screen. Sometimes I'm able to press a button or two like it's going to work, and then it will go to the title screen. Sometimes it crashes completely and has to be restarted. Sometimes that even produces an error message and the option to send an error report.

This is terrible. I often play phone games for less than a minute at a time, and would like to be able to pick up where I left off. When it quits in the middle of a battle, I sometimes lose the resources spent to start the battle. Sometimes, I try to auto a whole battle, and it quits and dies before they even finish the last wave.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening, either through the game or through my phone's settings?

Other games I play, such as Final Fantasy Brave Exvius, do not have this problem. I can resume a battle in Exvius hours later.

I'm playing on a Samsung Galaxy S4 Active.

Comment: As far as I know, there is only one thing you could do: Ensure a stable internet connection and playing with no apps in the background so as RAM is available for DC Legends. This issue is faced by many players.